# Multiple fields comparison in javascript

Tags: javascript, comparison, compare

Is there any short and neat way of finding an item in the following list with the given **searchObject** specifications?

```
var list = [
    { id:1, name: "foo", description: "description 1" },
    { id:2, name: "bar", description: "description 2" },
    { id:3, name: "baz", description: "description 3" },
];

var searchObject = { id: 2, name: "bar" };
```

The **searchObject** does **NOT** necessarily have all the properties of an item in the list. I need the operator between properties to be **AND** (id==2 && name=="bar"). The following is what I have come up with. Is there anything native in javascript that can do this?

```
for (var i in list) {
    var found = true;
    for (var p in searchObject) {
        if (list[i][p] !== searchObject[p]) {
            found = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found) return list[i];
}
```

Comment: Please do not use `for (x in y)` on arrays.  [It does NOT do what you think](http://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/36866)

Answer (score 3):

No, there's not a native way. Some people might like the following better because its more javascripty, but it certainly doesn't have the superb browser support that your original version has.

```
var matches = list.filter(function(arrElem){
    return Object.keys(searchObject).every(function(prop){
        return searchObject[prop] === arrElem[prop];
    });
});
```

Note that this returns an array with all matches, not just the first match like yours. Also note that unlike yours, this doesn't test for inherited enumerable properties on the `searchObject`, although you probably don't want to search for inherited properties.

ps, many of these "I wish js had a nicer way of doing X" desires are satisfied by [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/). In particular, the [findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) method is what you're after:

```
var match = _.findWhere(list, searchObject);
```

Comment: By "javascripty", you mean functional?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris kinda...maybe more like emphasizing javascripts unique blend of imperative OO w/ functional ideas.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience if the solution ever exists, it will not be much better than yours.

It is better to not use the `for...in` statement for arrays, because it enumerates properties of the array, not the elements. Consider the following:

```
Array.prototype.test = function () { };
for (var i in q) console.log(i);
```

This code will output `test` which is probably not what you may expect.

Anyway, for this kind of things I use `lo-dash`. Its `_.find(...)` method does exactly what you need and you may look at this method's source code, which I presume is most effective realization.